# Connect to openshift using `rhc ssh` on Windows without PuTTY

Tags: ssh, openshift

I have an Openshift app, and a Windows install with `ssh` provided by Git-for-Windows (under cmder). I do not have PuTTY installed.

When I run `rhc ssh app`, I get the error:

```
Connecting to <UID>@app-domain.rhcloud.com ...
Using username "<UID>".
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

If I run `rhc ssh -d app` to get better diagnostics, I end up with a trace containing:

```
DEBUG: Invoking Kernel.exec with ["C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\plink.exe", "-vv", "<UID>@app-domain.rhcloud.com"]
plink: unknown option "-vv"
```

...so it looks like `rhc ssh` is trying to use PuTTY. In fact, if I run

```
rhc ssh --ssh C:\Users\me\Downloads\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\bin\ssh.exe app
```

Then the connection works.

Can I setup rhc so that it tries to use the ssh I have installed, instead of looking for PuTTY?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww (and other closers) - I disagree with this close. openshift is a platform used by software developers, and rhc is a "software tool commonly used by programmers". I've asked a question which can be answered, and which only software developers would encounter. I think it would be On-Topic for SuperUser (but not for Unix/Linux, since it's a Windows issue), but is more specifically software development than is usual there. Can I improve the question in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the environment variable `PATH`, because rhc uses the default ssh client.

If you don't have PUTTY installed, the easiest solution is to add the C:\Users\me\Downloads\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\bin\ folder (which includes ssh.exe) to the PATH environment variable.

By the way, I suggest to move git-for-windows in another folder.